paragraph within paracol not shown on left column
I am preparing a large document where I need also to use paragraphs and subparagraphs. The following code snippets sets on both columns several headers, whereas the section headers on both columns appear, but the paragraph header intended for the left column is not shown in the document. Moreover, the paragraph intended to be shown in the right column is rendered in the left column. Current result attached. Who knows what is going wrong?
Thanks
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{easyReview}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2} 

\section{section left}
\switchcolumn
\section{section right}
\switchcolumn*

\subsection{subsection left}
\switchcolumn
\subsection{subsection right}
\switchcolumn*

\subsubsection{subsubsection left}
\switchcolumn
\subsubsection{subsubsection right}
\switchcolumn*

\paragraph{paragraph left}
\switchcolumn
\paragraph{\highlight{paragraph right}}
\switchcolumn*

\subparagraph{subparagraph left}
\switchcolumn
\subparagraph{subparagraph right} 
\switchcolumn*

Text left column
\switchcolumn
Text right column
\switchcolumn*

\end{paracol}
\end{document} 

Result:


Welcome to TeX.SE!

The \paragraph{} and \subparagraph{}commands are by default inline headers. What is after these commands matter, even when it is followed by blank lines,  because the next text will be part of the same paragraph. Simply is not a good place to switch the column. Add some text or at least a hard space (~) after these headers and all will be in the correct column.

